# Is there way to indicate architecture (32 or 64 bit) when configuring node js in azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I know that azure web sites/app respects the following element in package.json in node js application for configuring host node and desired npm:

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1",
    "npm": "4.6.1"
  }
```

Is there also a way to indicate require **either 32-bit or 64-bit** version of node for hosting in azure web apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Node.js (npm) `package.json` file has a **cpu** property that should achieve what you're looking for.

---

From the [npmjs package docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) -

> **cpu**
>   If your code only runs on certain cpu architectures, you can specify which ones.
>   `"cpu" : [ "x64", "ia32" ]`
>   Like the os option, you can also blacklist architectures:
>   `"cpu" : [ "!arm", "!mips" ]`
>   The host architecture is determined by **process.arch**

---

In your case, if you'd like to set your Azure environment to 32bit, simply set `"cpu" : [ "ia32" ]`; if you'd like the 64 bit environment, set it to `"cpu" : [ "x64" ]`.

Comment: I could not find CPU info in npm package.json documentation. Where is this documented? I was looking under engines section.

Comment: It is not under engines, but at the root level. Thanks.

Comment: What you have is correct already. For more complete solution, you can use: {
    "name": "mypackage",
    ...
    "engines": {
        "node": "6.11.1",
        "npm": "4.2.0"
    },
    "cpu": ["ia32"],
    "os": ["win32"],
    ...
}  Unfortunately, azure only supports 32 bit on windows os only at this time.